# how to create a folder and path in flask correctly

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I created a folder and path in flask as shown in the code below:

```
def add_video(form_video, loc, foldername1, foldername2):
    filename = secure_filename(form_video.filename)
    if len(filename) < 0:
        return False;
    randon_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    video_fn = randon_hex + f_ext     #filename
    """ create vide upload folder for each course uploaded by a user"""
    if loc == 'v_uploads':
        video_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static\\stylesheets\\v_uploads\\' + str(foldername1) + '\\' + str(foldername2),  video_fn )
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(video_path), exist_ok=True)
        form_video.save(video_path)
        """
        size = os.stat(video_path).st_size
        """
    return video_fn
```

This worked on my local host on my computer. But when the site was deployed remotely using unicorn and nginx, instead of creating the folders stylesheets/v_uploads/john/python/video.mp4, it created a folder named "static\stylesheets\v_uploads\john\video". I mean the upload path was not created correctly. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote host is running Linux, where `\` is not the directory separator character; it is a valid character in filenames.  So it did what you asked and created that literal filename.

Change your `join()` call to pass each component separately and it will assemble the path correctly, using the appropriate directory separator character for the host OS:

```
video_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static', 'stylesheets', 'v_uploads', str(foldername1), str(foldername2),  video_fn)
```

Comment: i changed from '\' to '/'